# Why won't this entry Insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to insert a new row into table Class Rights. When I execute this code and look at the table, it is not there / no changes were made. Why is this? Does it have anything to do with the seeding or possibly not declaring something correctly.

```
DECLARE @ID INT; 

IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM dbo.ClassRights WHERE FKClassID = 2100000000 )      
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.ClassRights (FKCategoryID, FKClassID, FKRightsID)
    SELECT 77, 2100000000, 4029
    FROM dbo.ClassRights
END



IF EXISTS (SELECT * from ClassRights)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @ID = ClassRightsID FROM ClassRights WHERE ClassRightsID < 1000000000 ORDER BY ClassRightsID DESC
    SET @ID = @ID + 1
    DBCC CHECKIDENT(ClassRights, RESEED, @ID)
END
```

Comment: Is there a trigger on `ClassRights`?

Comment: Please add table definition and sample data before the script is run.

Comment: Have you checked if you go inside the first `IF` or not?

Comment: If there is more one than existing row in ClassRights, your insert will try to insert multiple rows, do you get a duplicate key error? Your insert should be: INSERT INTO dbo.ClassRights (FKCategoryID, FKClassID, FKRightsID) VALUES (77, 2100000000, 4029)

Comment: @Eric When I executed: INSERT INTO dbo.ClassRights (FKCategoryID, FKClassID, FKRightsID)
    SELECT 77, 2100000000, 4029
    FROM dbo.ClassRights It was able to insert.

Comment: @Larnu I do not believe there is

Comment: @JohnVasquez My question whether the condition `IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM dbo.ClassRights WHERE FKClassID = 2100000000 )` is satisfied or not.  If not, it will not execute the `INSERT`.

Comment: 2100000000 is bigger than 1000000000, so your 2nd part or query won't get the ClassRightsID 2100000000

Comment: Do you have any data in ClassRights to begin with?  Steve Ford's comment has another effect.  If there are rows, then multiple inserts will occur -- if there are no rows, no inserts will occur.  His values approach is the correct one.

Comment: @AdamYan so should I replace that with 2100000000?

Comment: @pwilcox Yes, there is existing data in there

Comment: I don't know you business rules for "ClassRightsID <1000000000" so I cannot tell whether your should remove it or not. And why do you reseed the identity in the begging anyway, is it really necessary?

Comment: @AdamYan 
 I reseed to make sure the classrights table would continue to insert with the proper classrightsID value because we want to avoid it inserting classrightsid values that are like greater than 1000000000